# Django query sets using CAST

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Hello guys I'm trying to order a string in a django queryset using CAST but I can not achieve the order, I need a hand.

```
s = Empresas.objects.filter(codigo__startswith="B") \
                .extra({'codigo_uint': "CAST(codigo as INTEGER)"}) \
                .order_by('-codigo_uint')

for x in s:
    print x.codigo
```

what I got is:

```
B-001
B-999
B-1000
B-897
B-010
B-099
B-100
B-500
B-9999
```

How can I get the correct order of this ?
I really appreciate the help

models.py

```
class Empresas(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Comment: It's difficult to answer without knowing what is your modelisation. Can you show the code of your `Empresas` and maybe `Codigo` models ?

Comment: Thank you, I already added,

Comment: It depends on the database. PostgreSQL raises an exception `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "B-001"` while MySQL converts all these mixed strings to zero. The function CAST is not useful for your purpose.